# How to add new items to a list of filled arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a book list as below

```
public static ArrayList<List<String>> booksList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

And it is filled as shown below

```
booksList.add(Arrays.asList("Coders at Work", null));
booksList.add(Arrays.asList("Code Complete",null));
booksList.add(Arrays.asList("The Mythical Man Month",null));
booksList.add(Arrays.asList("Don't Make Me Think",null));
booksList.add(Arrays.asList("The Pragmatic Programmer",null));
```

I want to add items to list of specific row of `Arraylist`

```
booksList.get(0).add("BUYED");
booksList.get(0).add(0,"BUYED");
```

But it doesn't work. How to add more items? or Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot add or remove elements of a `List` created by `Arrays.asList()`.

Its javadoc states indeed :

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

To be able to add new elements after the list was created, you could wrap the fixed size List in a new `ArrayList`.

For example this :

```
BooksList.add(Arrays.asList("Coders at Work", null));
```

could be written :

```
BooksList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Coders at Work", null)));
```